# Unable to access html elements by tag using Java script

Tags: javascript, html

My html is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>
                Event Handling
            </title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <h1> This is the chapter in which I am handling Events.The site you should visit is: </h1>
            <a href="http://w3schools.com"> <b>here<b> </a>

            <script src="events.js"></src>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The javascript is like this:

```
var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

link.onclick = MyEventHandler;

function MyEventHandler()
{
    alert("ouch!");
    return false;
}
```

It is not working, but using inling event handler I am doing it successfully. Please helop me.

Comment: I don't think you intended to do `link.onclick = false`

Comment: You need to close your `script` tag with `</script>`, for one.

Comment: @KevinB I have edited..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the event handler function, not the return value of calling that function.

```
link.onclick = MyEventHandler;
```

(Also note that you need to use the end tag `</script>` not `</src>`.)

Comment: Yes, you are right...The problem was with missing </script>. Thanks